# Output result of grep to var then to system file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, environment-variables

There is a parameter that I need to grep from a file and then I need to get that parameter into another file.  I need to read the variable at boot time and have it inserted in

```
$grep "id" /file/one | cut -d " " -f2
$12345
```

So now I have the `ID_VAR` of 12345.  Now what I would like to do is use this in `/file/two`

In `file/two`:

```
...
@program ID_VAR
...
```

Is there a way to run the grep function inside file two?  Is there a way to share a variable between files?  I am using Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` an `id` from one file and append to another file prepended with the string `@program`:

`echo '@program' $(grep "id" file/one | cut -d " " -f2) >> file/two`

Answer (score 1):

There are some ambiguities in your question, but I think this snippet of script is what you are looking for:

Assuming `@program` is already in your file 2: (otherwise, see sudo_o's solution)

```
ID_VAR=$(grep "id" /file/one | cut -d " " -f2)
sed -i "s/@program/@program ${ID_VAR}/" /file/two
```

**Explanation:**

- `ID_VAR=$(...)`: save of the result of your `grep` and `cut` into `ID_VAR`
- `sed`: invoke `sed` and use the `-i` option to edit the input file in place
- `"s/@program/@program ${ID_VAR}/"`: replace `@program` with `@program (value of ID_VAR)` in the input file
- `/file/two`: what your input file is